# How to manipulate TEXT, NTEXT data from sql server trigger

Tags: sql-server-2005

i hard that TEXT, NTEXT data can not be manipulated from sql server trigger. is it true. if not then please explain how could i manipulate  TEXT, NTEXT data from sql server trigger.
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use text or ntext. Use nvarchar(max) or varchar(max)

Harsh, but they have been deprecated for a reason...

Edit, just remembered. [You may be able to use INSTEAD OF triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669551/how-to-get-use-text-columns-in-a-trigger)

Comment: thanks for ur answer...can u plzz give me sample instead of trigger from where text or ntext has been accessed.