# instead of trigger and text ntext datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to manipulate TEXT, NTEXT data from sql server trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734706/how-to-manipulate-text-ntext-data-from-sql-server-trigger)

how we can manipulate text and ntext data type with the help of instead of trigger. can anyone give me any sample.

thanks

Comment: Same user, same question [How to manipulate TEXT, NTEXT data from sql server trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734706/how-to-manipulate-text-ntext-data-from-sql-server-trigger). Any example will be in this MSDN link. Or any other trigger example.

Comment: And holy cow does this guy ask a lot of questions!  At least he votes a lot too :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look in the MSDN for this issue. [Using text, ntext, and image Data in INSTEAD OF Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175196.aspx)