# How to manipulate the TEXT column of DELETED/INSERTED tables in SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, text, triggers

I have a SQL Server table and I need to code a trigger to fire when there is an update on that table.

There is a `Text` column in this table. I need to compare the old and new value of that column after the update, from the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables.

The thing is that I absolutely can't change the type of that column.

Does anyone have found a way to bypass this restriction in a SQL Server trigger ?

Comment: You **cannot** use a `Text` column in a trigger - no trick, no hack, no way to bypass that - and you **should NOT** use `text` anymore anyway - so really, the only option you have **IS** to change that column's datatype - otherwise, you simply **CANNOT** use it in the trigger

Comment: That's why i am asking such a question. I can't change the column's datatype and i still need to deal with it, in a way or an other.

Comment: If you cannot change the datatype, nor can you change the update query - then I'm afraid there's simply no way to do this. You cannot use this datatype in a trigger - and yet, the trigger is the only option to handle your situation. Sorry - but this just **won't work** - you'll have to change either the datatype, or the way the data is inserted - as it is, there is **no solution**

Comment: There is an answer to your question already but would require quite a bit of work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669551/how-to-get-use-text-columns-in-a-trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do something else, I don't really like it, but it allows me to use a varchar column instead of the text column. So I did this :

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable]
ADD [MyVarcharColumn] AS (CONVERT([nvarchar(MAX)],[MyTextColumn]))
```

With this computed column, I don't need to edit any existing queries or .EDMX (Entity Framework) of an existing project, and my trigger works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a trigger would it possible for you to amend your update query?  Here's an example update that returns the before and after values:

```
-- Declare a table to hold our sample data.
DECLARE @Example TABLE
    (
        TextField       VARCHAR(255)
    )
;

-- Populate it.
INSERT INTO @Example
    (
        TextField
    )
VALUES
    ('a'),
    ('b'),
    ('c')
;

-- Update the text field and view the change
UPDATE
    @Example
SET
    TextField = 'z'
OUTPUT
    deleted.TextField   AS Old_TextField,
    inserted.TextField  AS New_TextField
;
```

You could also use the INTO clause to capture this output into a new table.

For more on the INSERTED and DELETED tables see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx).

Comment: Have you looked into change tracking (2008 and above)?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964713.aspx

Comment: Working on a 2005 SQL Server :(